# Why a Pipeline keeps stuck in queued status forever in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I've a Pipeline to execute several Data Flows with in Azure Data Factory, some weeks ago it was running properly and lasted around 25 minutes to finish, I've had to make a little adjustment in one filter (specifically, it was in the last and only Data Flow that keeps in queued forever, this Data Flow inserts into SQL DB). After the adjustment, without explanation everytime Pipeline is running it just keeps static on queued status and never ends

Comment: I found that if I change the scaling settings of Spark executors and scale down the job, it works, but not always. I was trying to run an apache spark job on Synapse, but  I think my use-case is similar to this question.

Answer (score 0):

First think check if the indexes exists on the Synapse tables/related tables where you sink your data, make sure indexes are disabled or dropped when you ingest data and enable it on the last step.